# Golang: How to use vgo? error: "cannot find package"

Tags: go, vgo

1. I have a project which is currently under my GOPATH `/usr/local/go/src/`
2. Then I went inside my project root and ran: `go get -u golang.org/x/vgo`
3. In my main.go I want to use lib httprouter so I added in import statement:

   `import (
     "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
   )`
4. I ran `vgo build`
5. Then when I start to run my server as usual I get the following error:

`main.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter (from $GOPATH)`

I understand the error, it seems to be searching for httprouter under GOPATH or GOROOT. So do I have to do anything else to just let vgo do its thing and I can run my server successfully?

Comment: Before doing `vgo build` like in normal `go` you need to ran `vgo get` in your project directory

Comment: did you go get github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter?

Comment: Did you create an empty `go.mod` file before running `vgo build`? Did `vgo build` generate the contents of `go.mod`? Does `go.mod` contain `httprouter`? When you say "start to run my server," what command did you run?

Answer (score 4):

## Using `vgo build`

Here is a "Hello, World" walk-through of using `vgo`, including common errors and how to respond to them.

1. `$ go get -u golang.org/x/vgo`
2. `$ cd /tmp/hello # Outside of GOPATH.`
3. `$ cat main.go`

   ```
   package main

   import "fmt"

   func main() {
       fmt.Println("Hello, World")
   }
   ```
4. `$ vgo build`

   ```
   cannot determine module root; please create a go.mod file there
   ```
5. This error tells us we need to specify what the root of our vgo module is. A module is a collection of packages (possibly one) versioned together. Create an empty `go.mod` file to signify this is the module root:

   ```
   $ touch go.mod
   ```
6. Try building again: `$ vgo build`.

   ```
   vgo: cannot determine module path for source directory
   /tmp/hello (outside GOPATH, no import comments)
   ```
7. This error tells us vgo doesn't know the import path of our package. There are two ways to tell it:

   1. Add a `module` statement to `go.mod`.
   2. Add an `import` comment to our package.

   We'll go with option 2 right now and come back to option 1. Change the first line of `main.go` to be:

   ```
   package main // import "my/import/path/hello"
   ```
8. `$ vgo build` one last time.
9. Run the binary: `$ ./hello`

   ```
   Hello, World
   ```

Note: `go.mod` now contains a `module` line (option 1 above):

```
$ cat go.mod 
module my/import/path/hello
```

**If you are inside your `GOPATH`**, the error in step 5 should not occur - `vgo build` should automatically figure out you're inside your `GOPATH` and add the `module` line accordingly.

---

## Using `vgo run` (without using `vgo build`)

For this example, lets use the `hello.go` from the [A Tour of Versioned Go (vgo)](https://research.swtch.com/vgo-tour):

1. `$ go get -u golang.org/x/vgo`
2. `$ mkdir /tmp/hello2`
3. `$ curl -sS https://swtch.com/hello.go >hello.go`
4. `$ vgo run hello.go`

   ```
   cannot determine module root; please create a go.mod file there
   ```
5. `$ touch go.mod`
6. `$ vgo run hello.go`

   ```
   vgo: resolving import "rsc.io/quote"
   vgo: finding rsc.io/quote (latest)
   vgo: adding rsc.io/quote v1.5.2
   Hello, world.
   ```

Comment: thanks for answer. I wonder can you include parallel step of run but without binary, I normally do go run main.go, when developing I also use some autoreloaded, `gin` what would be the equivalent of go run main.go with vgo?

Comment: You can run `vgo run` directly. :) I updated the answer with an example.